# Changing SearchLayout with metadata API

Tags: api, metadata-api, jsforce, search-layout

I'm trying to update SearchLayouts using the metadata API via jsforce.  I am basically Retrieving the CustomObject (it's for Account but I think I need to do this to change the SearchLayout), removing a field from "searchResultsAdditionalFields" and from "lookupDialogsAdditionalFields", then using the metadata Update to set it.  While I get no errors, the SearchLayout just doesn't change.

Any ideas why it's not updating with update or any other approaches I can take to update SearchLayouts with the API?

Comment: You're retrieving and deploying the CustomObject in the manifest and it's a recent API version? Also are <profileSearchLayouts> in the custom object? This will override the default <searchLayouts> section.

Comment: I'm using JSForce, so I'm using the read and update calls in JSForce.  I'm not using profileSearchLayouts

Comment: What version number is in the JSForce method call? Where are you verifying the deployment? Through setup or by doing a global search?

Comment: Looks like I'm using 42.0, and I've been verifying by calling read again if that's what you mean?

Comment: Give 51.0 a shot. By verifying I mean looking under the object manager in Salesforce at the search layout and seeing if it's taking.

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't actually looking, I was just using the API to fetch it again after it was supposed to be updated.  I will try 51, thanks!

Comment: Okay well looks like when I go to the UI in Setup it's there, and when I look at the search view or read again with jsforce it's not. Oof.  So makes me think it's related to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59784/metadata-api-searchlayouts-not-showing-updates

Comment: Aaand after I click around a bit it starts to show up in both :). Thanks for the tip to check in the UI. If you want to answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The takeaway here is to verify Metadata API operations in the target org if things look like they're not deploying correctly and always use the most recent API version in the operations.

There is an issue in the metadata API where the SearchLayouts need to be "jiggled" before the update in the UI due to caching.  You can do this with the API as described in this response [Metadata API SearchLayouts not showing updates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59784/metadata-api-searchlayouts-not-showing-updates) or by going to the UI and searching for the relevant object.